# Balanced duplicate bank account detection

Tags: balanced-payments

I've create a new merchant account on Balanced via the API. I added a bank account to this account and then tokenized the exact same bank account and then added that again. I was expecting the second association to throw a 409 telling me that the account could not be added.

I have two questions:

1. Why does the API allow me to add the exact same bank account / card to an account twice?
2. How can I detect this and not add the bank account / card to the account?

Here is the example of two bank accounts I've created on an account via the Ruby gem:

```
irb(main):029:0> @bank_accounts.items.each { |a| 
  puts "#{a["bank_name"]} #{a["bank_code"]} created-#{a["created_at"]} #{a["last_four"]} uri=#{a["uri"]} id=#{a["id"]}"
}; nil
123456789 created-2012-07-11T23:36:57.290555Z 2333 uri=/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP4Z4RaRDF6TWqeupiVUSu8m/accounts/AC2tip2eDhi92THXXEkIdys1/bank_accounts/BA2mP9GtEPVB3v9DzWJ7ZH8B id=BA2mP9GtEPVB3v9DzWJ7ZH8B
123456789 created-2012-07-11T23:37:22.655007Z 2333 uri=/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP4Z4RaRDF6TWqeupiVUSu8m/accounts/AC2tip2eDhi92THXXEkIdys1/bank_accounts/BA2PlMIVFyMSSzo2zzUZb2XA id=BA2PlMIVFyMSSzo2zzUZb2XA
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no constraint on adding duplicate bank accounts and cards as you note. This was a decision made to allow the developer to lessen the burden of writing code for catching duplicate bank accounts. Your feedback is noted and appreciated.
2. You can index the cards or bank accounts associated with a user, Balanced does not return the full card number but by comparing the last_four, expiration, and name you can tell if a card is a match, similar fields are available for bank accounts but swap expiration with bank_code (routing number).

   The code to do something like this in Ruby would be:

   ```
   require 'balanced'

   Balanced.configure 'e1c5ad38d1c711e1b36c026ba7e239a9'

   # duplicate cards
   card1 =  Balanced::Card.new(:card_number=>"4111111111111111", :expiration_month=>"12", :expiration_year=>"2020").save()  # original card
   card2 =  Balanced::Card.new(:card_number=>"4111111111111111", :expiration_month=>"12", :expiration_year=>"2020").save()  # our duplicate card
   card3 =  Balanced::Card.new(:card_number=>"4111111111111111", :expiration_month=>"12", :expiration_year=>"2021").save()  # a different card

   # create a new account
   buyer = Balanced::Account.new(:email_address => '%d@example.org' % Time.now).save()
   buyer.add_card(card1.uri)

   # helper function
   def has_card(cards, card)
      cards.map { |c| c.last_four == card.last_four && c.expiration_month == card.expiration_month && c.expiration_year == card.expiration_year }.include? true
   end

   puts 'buyer already has this card' if has_card(buyer.cards, card2)
   puts 'buyer does not have this card' if not has_card(buyer.cards, card3)
   ```

Comment: Balanced has just rolled out a [`hash` parameter](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/blob/master/resources/cards.rst#card-view) for cards. This will be  rolled out retroactively to bank accounts in the near future. You can use this to search for duplicates by querying the cards endpoint `/v1/marketplaces/M123/cards?hash=XXX`